# ADFS 2016 On behalf of flow : cannot get any user informations

Tags: .net-core, openid-connect, openid, adfs4.0

I'm trying to implement the "on behalf of" flow in an application using ADFS 2016 as STS. As a reference, I look at this Microsoft tutorial (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-ca/windows-server/identity/ad-fs/development/ad-fs-on-behalf-of-authentication-in-windows-server). It's working as it should, I can login into my web application and then use my original access token in UserAssertion to generate a new access token with the proper audience to call my API BUT I found absolutely no way to include any user informations (sub, name, email, upn etc.) into the access token for my API, even if I set claim rules into my ADFS configurations for the API.

I checked the communication between my app and adfs using Fiddler and everything looks like the  informations in the tutorial. See the screen shot of the "on behalf of" request below :

[image]

Here's the resulting access token :

[image]

Finally, here's the code I use to generate my new access token :

```
private async Task<string> GetAccessToken(ClaimsPrincipal user, string originalAccessToken)
{
    var authority = "[authority]";
    var context = new AuthenticationContext(authority, false);
    string userName = user.FindFirstValue("upn");
    var userAssertion = new UserAssertion(originalAccessToken, "urn:ietf:params:oauth:grant-type:jwt-bearer",userName);
    var cc = new ClientCredential("https://localhost:44387/", "[client_secret]");

    var result = await context.AcquireTokenAsync("https://localhost:44339/", cc, userAssertion);

    return result.AccessToken;
}
```

Have you struggle with that scenario and if yes, did you find a way to fix this ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I've only used the Microsoft On Behalf Of flow with Azure AD and not ADFS, but it looks like you need to send a more detailed scope in your User Info request.

Maybe try sending 'openid profile email', to indicate that you want that type of detail, as in [Section 17](https://authguidance.com/2017/12/01/azure-ad-spa-code-sample/) of my blog post. Of course this assumes that this type of data has been registered for all users.

**TROUBLESHOOTING**

Looks like one of these will be the cause:

- A suboptimal Microsoft library that does not allow you to send the required scope
- Or ADFS 2016 perhaps lacks the scope features that work correctly in Azure AD

I would concentrate on making extra sure you are sending the correct form URL encoded request message, using a tool such as curl, Postman or a plain C# HttpClient. Here is the code I used to send the correct scope - using an open source library rather than a Microsoft one:

- [Sample NodeJS Code](https://github.com/gary-archer/oauth.websample.azure/blob/master/api/src/host/oauth/authenticator.ts#L128)

If you can get the scope sent correctly then you should have a resolution either way:

- Either you get the correct data and can update your code
- Or the behaviour you want is not supported by ADFS

Good luck ...

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't work. I tried to do it with the code but there's no way to add claims to AcquireTokenAsync if client credentials are used. So I tried by hand crafting the post request and adding the profile and email claims but the result is the same. Any other ideas ?

Comment: I updated my answer - focus on trying to get the scope string right ...